# Angular "wait" dialog is not displaying

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm implementing a dialog with a mat-spinner while page data is loading.  I'm working with Angular v14.  I'm using a dialog, instead of a plain spinner, because I'll need to pass some information in it.  The problem I'm having is, the dialog doesn't display unless I put a break point immediately after it.  My understanding of Angular is its synchronous so the code to show the dialog should complete before loading the data, yes?  However, I also tried adding a setTimeout to my LoadData method to give it extra time.  But the dialog never appears.

The dialog is its own component

```
<h3 mat-dialog-title>Please Wait</h3>

<mat-dialog-content>
  <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:space-around ">
      We're getting your data...
    <mat-spinner [diameter]="20"></mat-spinner>
  </div>
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions></mat-dialog-actions>
```

The typescript file is empty

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-spinner',
  templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.css']
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public spinnerRef: MatDialogRef<SpinnerComponent>
  ) { }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

I'm loading the spinner and data in a component ngOnInit:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.showSpinner();
    setTimeout(() => this.loadData(), 3000);
    this.hideSpinner();
  }
```

Here are the showSpinner and hideSpinner functions:

```
private showSpinner(): void {

    const spinnerConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    spinnerConfig.disableClose = true;
    spinnerConfig.autoFocus = true;
    spinnerConfig.width = '400px';
    spinnerConfig.height = '150px';
    spinnerConfig.closeOnNavigation = false;
    spinnerConfig.disableClose = true;
    spinnerConfig.hasBackdrop = true;

    this.spinner.open(SpinnerComponent, spinnerConfig)
  }

  private hideSpinner(): void {
    this.spinner.closeAll()
  }
```

The load data methods makes several service calls to get data for drop down fields.  This is an example, and there are 4 function calls in total

```
  private loadData(): void {
    this.projectService.getAllProjects().subscribe((data) => {
      this.projects = data;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("an error occured in the project service");
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not awaiting the async process of loading the data. This means that this code is executed synchronously, but the callback inside of the `setTimeout` method is executed asynchronously:

```ts
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.showSpinner();
  setTimeout(() => this.loadData(), 3000);
  this.hideSpinner();
}
```

As a result, the loading spinner opens, but immediately closes again.

You can fix it by awaiting the result of the `loadData` method. With this code the execution is paused until the `loadData` method returns a result:

```ts
async ngOnInit() {
  this.showSpinner();
  await this.loadData();
  this.hideSpinner();
}
```

But to achieve this you have to make sure that the `loadData` method can be awaited. This can be done like this:

```ts
private async loadData() {
  const data = await lastValueFrom(this.projectService.getAllProjects());
  this.projects = data;
}
```

Now, we're awaiting the response of our projectService with the RxJS operator `lastValueFrom`. This means that it waits until it got the last value from the HTTP request which is in our case the list of projects. By using the `async` keyword the `loadData` method is automatically returning a Promise that can be awaited by our ngOnInit method.

**StackBlitz Example**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-59cr8m?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example.ts

Comment: Philipp, great answer and it works perfectly.  I appreciate the time you put into explaining the issue.  I have more studying to do!